# numpy array with n prefilled columns

Tags: python, numpy

I need to specialized numpy arrays.  Assume I have a function:

```
    def gen_array(start, end, n_cols):
```

It should behave like this, generating three columns where each column goes from start (inclusive) to end (exclusive):

```
>>> gen_array(20, 25, 3)
array([[20, 20, 20],
       [21, 21, 21],
       [22, 22, 22],
       [23, 23, 23],
       [24, 24, 24]])
```

My rather naïve implementation looks like this:

```
def gen_array(start, end, n_columns):
    a = np.arange(start, end).reshape(end-start, 1) # create a column vector from start to end
    return np.dot(a, [np.ones(n_columns)])          # replicate across n_columns
```

(It's okay, though not required, that the `np.dot` converts values to floats.)

I'm sure there's a better, more efficient and more numpy-ish way to accomplish the same thing.  Suggestions?

### Update

Buildin on a suggestion by @msi_gerva to use `np.tile`, my latest best thought is:

```
def gen_array(start, end, n_cols):
    return np.tile(np.arange(start, end).reshape(-1, 1), (1, n_cols))
```

... which seems pretty good to me.

Comment: One way to do this: `a = np.tile(np.arange(20,25,1),(3,1)).T` . Not very elegant (using transpose in the end), but at least a one-liner.

Comment: `tile` looks good - How about reshaping first: `a = np.tile(np.arange(20,25)).reshape(-1,1), (1, 3))`

Comment: Instead of `dot` just multiply, `a * np.ones(n_columns)`.  That's a (5,1) times a (3,) broadcasting to (5,3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `numpy.arange` and `numpy.reshape`, use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html?highlight=repeat#numpy.repeat) to extend your data.

```py
import numpy as np

def gen_array(start, end, n_cols):
    return np.arange(start, end).repeat(n_cols).reshape(-1, n_cols)

print(gen_array(20, 25, 3))
# [[20 20 20]
#  [21 21 21]
#  [22 22 22]
#  [23 23 23]
#  [24 24 24]]
```

Comment: That feels more logical (and perhaps more efficient) than using tile().  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I found:

The [:,None] adds a dimension to the array.

```
np.arange(start, end)[:,None]*np.ones(n_cols)
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't allow you to specify the number of columns as a parameter.  How would you create 25 columns?

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect your variable names, the  [:,None] creates the extra dimension, and the np.ones determines the size via broadcasting

Answer (score 0):

```
np.arange(start, end)[:, np.newaxis].repeat(n_cols, axis=1)
```